# Запуск exe файла через action script

Tags: actionscript

Мне надо запустить `.exe` файл с именем `gamestat.exe`, который находится на пк пользователя через `action script`.

Comment: а action script небось с браузера (через флеш) запускается?

Comment: Да с браузера

Comment: тогда, никак. Это же главная фишка. Представьте себе на секунду, что это было бы возможно. Сотни сайтов бы запускали `format c:` (конечно же команда была бы другой, это исключительно для примера) и миллионы хомячков плакали и не устанавливали флеш.

Answer (score 2):

Запуск exe файла из AS запрещен политикой безопасности.

Answer (score 1):

Так сделать нельзя.

Но если очень надо... Ты можешь декомпилировать и разобрать по кусочкам опкоды плеера, браузера, сопоставить с форматом swf и попробовать поискать лазейки. Технология flash содержит в себе ряд лазеек(которые периодически закрываются).

PS А вообще, не стоит заниматься "злым хакерством".. Представь, что exe запустили у тебя на компе, и все твои пароли забрали. =)